# Images are placed behind other pictures(masonry plugin)

Tags: jquery, image, css, lightbox, jquery-masonry

I trying to use masonry plugin that arrange the images.
some how some of the images are placed behind other images.

this is the code: http://asher-gallery.com/
if it's work propely try to refresh the browser then it will make some mistake.

And another little question when I am opening the image with lightbox(addon) in smartphone
the lightboxOverlay it goes right instead of all over the screen.

thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The reason why the images was placed behind other are because i did not give them "height".

I Have found a solution for the lightbox problem on smartphones browsers.
you should place a META viewport content="width=**PAGE'S WIDTH**"
and this fixed my problem.